# Passing TextBlock HyperLink data to HyperLink.Click handler as HyperlinkClickEventArgs

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp

I thought this was straightforward but could not figure out how to pass on data value that will be retrieved in the Click handler. (Note: You need the **using Windows.UI.Xaml.Documents** directive if you wish to experiment with it).

```
Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink();

// Set various propertis such as hyperlink.Foreground, hyperlink.UnderlineStyle

// add the hyperlink text
hyperlink.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "click me!" });

// subscribe to handler shown below, but I want to pass on a string parameter that
// shows up as (HyperlinkClickEventArgs) e.OriginalSource or even as e.ToString()
// in the Click handler

hyperlink.Click += Hyperlink_Click;  // STUCK HERE in attempting to pass string data


// The hyperlink click event handler -- the sender object is as expected as commented.

private static void Hyperlink_Click(Hyperlink s, HyperlinkClickEventArgs e)
{
    string clickMeString = (s?.Inlines[0] as Run)?.Text; // no problem here!

    // ... BUT I want my parameter as e.OriginalSource to get to more data, but how?
}
```

Comment: var text = ((e.OriginalSource as Hyperlink).Inlines[0] as Run).Text;

Comment: I haven't managed to pass on in the first place. I have no problem manipulating the retrieval in the click handler.

Comment: why dont you use `HyperlinkButton` and pass parameter in `Tag`? I can post answer if you like

Comment: Sorry it has to be HyperLink for the requirement as part of a document string based on TextBlock. I have used HyperlinkButton in different situation without a problem. I understand the challenge with HyperLink is that it is not a control and has no **Tag** or Style setting etc. There must be a way to pass data though. Thanking you for the kind offer.

Comment: damn can't create `CustomControl` from `Hyperlink` either as its sealed. I'm stumped too :(

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of creating an **event delegate** to which you can inject the **HyperlinkClickEventArgs**  event data. I could be wrong but I don't think a more elaborate solution like CustomControl is necessary.